# Is it possible to define font-size in terms of the width or height of the containing div?

Tags: html, css

I know that I can define it in terms of the entire viewport with `vw` and `vh`, but is there a way I can define it in terms of the containing div?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no, this cannot be done in CSS. You will need javascript :/

Comment: You can use JavaScript for this (calculate width of the div and set the css for the font).

Comment: Rather than a containing div, you could use a containing iframe with a data URI or a srcdoc...

Comment: @MrLister Because on my page the containing divs are in the dozens, that would be a lot of iframes

Comment: @LarsUlrich are you open to using JavaScript?

Comment: @JacobGray I know how to do it using Javascript, but it's because I have to define the function, fire it when the document is ready, then fire it every time the window resizes

Comment: @LarsUlrich I think that is what you will probably have to do if you want it to work

Comment: @LarsUlrich The _window_ resizes? So it's about `vw`s after all?

Comment: Why do you need it, could there be another solution to your problem other than defining the font-size?

Comment: Yes, I think it's time you showed us an actual use case.